# RestKit Mapping with unsuccessful status codes

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map a 403 forbidden respone to a custom object. I registered a mapping with the response code as follows:

```
RKResponseDescriptor* tacResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:termsAndConditionMapping pathPattern:@"user" keyPath:nil statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:403]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:tacResponseDescriptor];
```

But when the `403` response is send from the server, I just get a '`Non-successful status code encountered: performing mapping with nil target object`' log from RestKit and the failure block is executed with the operation's `mappingResult` property being `nil`. What am I doing wrong here? I need to map one specific error case of a specific path to a specific object.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but there's no mappingResult property if you end up in the failure block. But the error can be found hidden in the `operation` property:

```
[[[operation.error userInfo] objectForKey: RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey] firstObject];
```

Comment: That's what worked for me. Also, your mapping will be applied and you can get properly mapped object.

Answer (score 0):

When the response status code is not 2xx the failure block will be called, you can catch your custom error there, switching on `operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode`

If you want to handle errors with RestKit, in a more generic way, you can consider to add to your RKObjectManager a response descriptor for all 4xx and 5xx errors - in this example i'll map error with this body structure

```
{"errorCode":"996","errorMessage":"This is my custom error message"}
```

Configure your RKObjectManager:

```
RKObjectMapping* errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"errorMessage" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"userInfo"]];
NSIndexSet *clientErrorStatusCode = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError); // Any response in the 4xx
NSIndexSet *serverErrorStatusCode = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassServerError); // Any response in the 5xx
RKResponseDescriptor *clientErrorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:clientErrorStatusCode];
RKResponseDescriptor *serverErrorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:serverErrorStatusCode];
//... Remember to add response descriptors to your object manager
```

And then in the failure block of your requests you can switch on the status code and handle the error:

```
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKErrorMessage *errorMessage = [[error.userInfo objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey] firstObject];
    NSString *errorCode = [errorMessage.userInfo objectForKey:@"errorCode"];

    if (operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode == 304){
         //Handle your 304 error
    }
}
```